# Android device's Uptime not restarting after rebooting it programmatically

Tags: android, service, android-4.4-kitkat, reboot, uptime

I developed an app that has system priveleges. It is able to successfully reboot the device and also shut it down. The problem is that after rebooting the device its `uptime` (`SystemClock.uptimeMillis()`) counter does not go back to `0` instead it keeps adding to its former value.

For instance, if the uptime value before rebooting was 300 seconds after rebooting it will keep adding up from 300 seconds instead of reseting the counter to `0`.

The code I'm using is the following:

```
    IPowerManager powerManager = IPowerManager.Stub.asInterface(
            ServiceManager.getService(Context.POWER_SERVICE));
    try {
        if(doReboot) {
            Log.v("Provisioning Manager", "PowerUtil: reiniciando Kitkat");
            powerManager.reboot(false, null, false);
        } else {
            Log.v("Provisioning Manager", "PowerUtil: apagando Kitkat");
            powerManager.shutdown(false, false);
        }
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I also used the following:

```
    if(doReboot) {
        Log.v("Provisioning Manager", "PowerUtil: reiniciando JellyBean");
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        pm.reboot(null);
    } else {
        Log.v("Provisioning Manager", "PowerUtil: apagando JellyBean");
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{ "su", "-c", "reboot -p"});
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The app has two processes the main process orderes the reboots and shut downs and the second process executes both orders. Clearly both of them do more than that but related to the problem, that is what they do.

Does someone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Actually both ways are correct the problem was that I was executing them on the background process. For whatever reason I still have not been able to find, running it on the background process did not fully reboot the device. The animations were shown and everything looked like a normal reset but the device's `SystemClock.uptimeMillis()` and `SystemClock.elapsedRealime()` were not reset.

After running the reset code on the main process both `SystemClock.uptimeMillis()` and `SystemClock.elapsedRealime()` went back to `0`.